# haproxy use a query parameter as a header

Tags: query-string, haproxy

I need to read one parameter from the query string and use is a heather. i tried a few option but none seems to work. Here is my example

--- sample query ---

https://www.testdomain.com/something?param1=foo&param2=bar

--ha-proxy frontend --

frontend lb_test

```
bind :443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem

mode http
```

acl the_param2 { query -m sub -i param2= }

http-request add-header X-VALUE the_param2

use_backend lb_test if the_param2

--- ha-proxy backend ---

backend lb_test

```
balance roundrobin

server srv1 x.x.x.x:<port_number> check
```

Thanks in advance!

regards

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `url_param` HTTP (layer 7) fetch, see [docs here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#7.3.6-url_param).

```
acl param2_exists url_param(param2) -m found
http-request set-header X-VALUE %[url_param(param2)] if param2_exists
```